# C# Mailkit delivery status notification

Tags: c#, notifications, mailkit

I am creating an email management system using MailKit.

I need to track delivery but all I can find is the `DeliveryStatusNotification enum`, but nowhere to apply it.

What I have so far is:

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
DeliveryStatusNotification delivery = 
  DeliveryStatusNotification.Delay |
  DeliveryStatusNotification.Failure |
  DeliveryStatusNotification.Never |
  DeliveryStatusNotification.Success;
message.Headers.Add(new Header(HeaderId.ReturnReceiptTo, "test@example.com")); // Delivery report
```

Guide me in the right direction??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is subclass SmtpClient and override the GetDeliveryStatusNotifications method:

```
class DSNSmtpClient : SmtpClient
{
    protected override DeliveryStatusNotification? GetDeliveryStatusNotifications (MimeMessage message, MailboxAddress mailbox)
    {
        if (/* some criteria for deciding whether to get DSN's... */)
            return DeliveryStatusNotification.Delay | 
                   DeliveryStatusNotification.Failure | 
                   DeliveryStatusNotification.Success;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: For pop3 how can I know of the delivery failed mail notifications from the Message object? Is there a sample somewhere I can look to  ?

Comment: Oops, that's read-receipt. It's very similar for status notification, just that it's a MessageDeliveryStatus instead of MessageDispositionNotification.

Comment: Yikes!  Why the design decision to force users to subclass it like that?

Comment: How else would you do it? What would be the API that *you* would design?

Comment: Perhaps add some properties that you can set on the Message rather than use a subclass would be nice

Comment: Why is everyone so afraid of subclassing? Having a message property does not allow the flexibility of subclassing and is not nearly as clean. People would also expect the property to persist through writing the message to a stream and re-parsing it (which it wouldn't because there's no MIME message property to serialize it as).

Comment: Probably because I am too dumb. But it does not work for me. 
I subclassed the SmtpClient as in your example, than instantiate the DNSSmtpClient and sent a message. 
But the GetDeliveryStatusNotifications from my subclass is never called. I get the failure notification from my mail server anyway, but never the Success notification.

Comment: Ah, I see. When debugging the source I see none of the smtp servers I use, handle DSN's